# How to sync multiple selection indices between two ListBoxes?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to move the selection from listbox1 to listbox2 with this code

```
if (listBox1.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            int selectedindex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
            for (int i =0 ; i < listBox1 .SelectedItems.Count; i++)
            {
                listBox2.SetSelected(selectedindex , true);
            }
        }
```

I got a result , but when I select more than one item in listbox1 it will only select one item in listbox2 which is the first one I've selected in listbox1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only storing one selection index of `listbox1` in `selectedIndex`. Later in the loop you are always instructing `listbox2` to set its selections to this one index.

Try this instead:

```
foreach (int index in listBox1.SelectedIndices)
{
    listBox2.SetSelected(index, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the [**SelectionMode**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selectedindex.aspx) property to allow multiple selections. You can set in property window or on load event.

```
listBox2.SelectionMode.MultiExtended = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;
```

Comment: the value of SelectionMode is MultiExtended but it didn't work
I tried to show it in message box like this
            
                `int selectedindex = listBox1.SelectedIndex;
                for (int i =0 ; i < listBox1 .SelectedItems.Count; i++)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(Convert .ToString  (selectedindex ));
                }`
            
it shows 0 in messagebox 3 times when I select 3 items
only when I select one item it shows it's index and once

Comment: I want the index not the items